# AppHarbor, BitBucket and SubRepo Work Around

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, appharbor, mercurial-subrepos

I would like to host a project on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). The project's [Hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) repository is hosted on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). The issue is that my repository contains a subrepo (also [Hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)). It seems there is no way for [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) to pull subrepos, so the project fails to build.

[AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) is aware of the issue and states that the solution is up to [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/):

- http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1578-bitbucket-hg-subrepos-are-not-downloaded-to-appharbor
- http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/4154-using-bitbucket-repo-with-sub-repo

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) has an open ticket, but no updates:

- https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/1500/archived-snapshots-dont-contain-subrepo

My question is, does anyone have a good workaround for this? I would be willing just to ftp the working directory to [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/), but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket modifying archive tarballs to include subrepos probably wouldn't be appropriate.

You, however, could easily set up something that builds your own tarballs that app harbor can handle and making them available to appharbor.  A cron job running somewhere that just does `hg pull ; hg update ; tar -czvf /docroot/workingdir.tar.gz workingdir` would be enough to create a web accessible tarball that app harbor could use.

The better fix is for app harbor to do a clone and and update instead of downloading a tarball.  Mercurial and git have in-built ways to get code, and tarball is a fallback not a primary mechanism.  For example popular CI systems like Jenkins use clone to get code, not tarball downloads, and resulting they work fine.

Comment: I may, begrudgingly, set that up. I do wish AppHarbor would do a clone + update instead. Subrepos seem to work fine for development purposes. I am not sure what differentiates AppHarbor's case that makes them choose the tarball method.

Comment: There's a couple of reasons we don't clone repositories:
1) We have a number of build engines running, so we'd have to do a full clone each time (and that's a heavier workload than just receiving the current version of the files).
2) We support a number of version control flavors, so we would have to maintain Git, Mercurial, Subversion and TFS, which isn't really providing any value to our core product.

Comment: I have never understood why Bitbucket and GitHub doesn't provide an option for packaging sub-repositories too. Your repository probably depend on some of that content so just omitting them isn't really helpful.

Comment: While it's probably out of scope for your project, you could actually use [our build API](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/3rd-party-integrations/using-appharbor-build-urls) to create an intermediary that first clones the repository and then packages it up nicely including the content of the sub-repositories. If someone made such a service, we'd definitely point users towards it.