# Deploy Subrepos to Appharbor

Tags: deployment, mercurial, bitbucket, appharbor, mercurial-subrepos

I am attempting to setup a deployment on appharbor for code hosted on bitbucket.  I have a number of projects that make use of a library project that I have, so I use subrepos to keep my code manageable.  This prevents appharbor from deploying because the subrepos aren't included in the download.

This post led me to why this problem occurs:

[AppHarbor, BitBucket and SubRepo Work Around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601486/appharbor-bitbucket-and-subrepo-work-around/11602192#11602192)

What I'm struggling with is how to implement the workaround that they stated.  Is this cron job/zip file something that I'm going to have to host myself or is it possible to do with just bitbucket and appharbor's post build events?  Thanks for any help that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicated workarounds, you might want to look into adding your library dependency as a NuGet package from a private feed. That could be hosted here: http://www.myget.org

Comment: This looks great!  I'm not entirely sure how to tie this into appharbor though.  Can you point me in the right direction?